# "Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource."

Tags: symfony, configuration

I'm writing a bundle that deals with a lot of dates and times and I'm not sure it's particularly possible to easily represent this easily with Yaml or XML. For the configuration I'm defining it as a PHP file, included() into the ...Extension::Load() function:

```
<?php
// {BundleName}Extension.php
$openingHours = require $path->locate('business_days.php');
$container->setParameter($alias . '.days', $openingHours['days']);

// business_days.php:
return array(
    'days' => array(
        Carbon::MONDAY => array(
            'name'  => 'Monday',
            'start' => (new Carbon('09:00'))->setDate(0, 0, 0)),
            'end'   => (new Carbon('17:00'))->setDate(0, 0, 0)),
        ),
        ....
);
```

When the system runs the configuration though (and successfully prepares the config), it then goes to dump the data to the file cache --

**"Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource."**

How can I - for this bundle - **not** have the configuration cached to disk, and so avoid the above error?

Comment: Make yourself a simple factory to create your business days then make a dependency injection factory service and inject it instead of a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is practical to turn off config caching on a per bundle basis.  Use a factory instead.

Code is untested:

```
class BusinessDaysFactory
{
    static function create()
    {
        return array(
            'days' => array(
                Carbon::MONDAY => array(
                    'name'  => 'Monday',
                    'start' => (new Carbon('09:00'))->setDate(0, 0, 0)),
                    'end'   => (new Carbon('17:00'))->setDate(0, 0, 0)),
    ),
    ....
# services.yml
business_days:
    class:  NeedAnEntry_ButItIsNotUsed
    factory_class:  Namespace\BusinessDaysFactory
    factory_method: create
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html